# why The Customize button in CMFCToolbar is ugly on large icons

Tags: c++, mfc, cmfctoolbar

When the toolbar is large the icon of the customize button is ugly how to fix this
[image]

as you see it is stretched and lead to bad resolution, is there anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're stuck with the way it looks unless you want to change the underlying code that renders the MFCToolBars object.  FYI, that class is based upon the BCG toolkit.  BCG does supply source code.

Comment: we wanted to get BCG but it don't support the RTL as they say specially on the grid control, so we will stay with this ugly icon, it is points and can be scaled easily but microsoft take the easy way for them and hard for those who follow them.